# SharePoint calendar in ios

Tags: ios, sharepoint, calendar

As I am new to iOS(Swift),I don't know whether we can display and use SharePoint calendar in iOS or not .
If we can, then please tell me the way to display and to access its events.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is topic has been here for awhile.

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/12219.aspx

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38782/sharepoint-calendar-sharing-on-iphone-and-ipad

Basically, there is no native approach to achieve this requirement, what Microsoft suggest is to use RSS. Also there are some third party solutions that with allow you to achieve this. However if you like to get your hands dirty and do it by yourself, there are some programmatic workarounds.

The one that I prefer because I know it works, is to use an Exchange Calendar, an iOS calendar can be connected to an Exchange Calendar.

Furthermore if you don't have a real dependency on your current SharePoint Calendar, you could simply migrate it to an Exchange Calendar, SharePoint is able to display Exchange Calendars natively, by doing this you will be able to access your calendar from SharePoint and iOS.

But lets say that you must preserve your current SharePoint Calendar and you cannot migrate it to Exchange, in this case you can sync your SharePoint Calendar with an Exchange Calendar programmatically, by using a SharePoint Event Receiver you can ensure that all your events will be replicated in your Exchange Calendar, you can use Exchange Object Model within your SharePoint Event Receiver code.

As you can imagine an Event Receiver is not the only alternative, there are other ways to achieve this by using different programmatic approaches, but you will need to invest some time to research this.

Comment: Thank you so much,but all I want is I just want to show SharePoint calendar for my app based on SharePoint web services,I don't want to link it with iPhone's inbuilt calender and how much I studied about exchange calender,it will link the SharePoint calendar with iPhone's calendar.